# How to convert a pdf bytes to an image byte

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, image-conversion

I have uploaded a PDF file and I convert it to byte format and save it in the database. On fetching the PDF byte array, I need to convert them  to image format so that I can insert the image into a new PDF report

```
SqlCommand objCmd = new SqlCommand(sTSQL, con);
            objCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            object result = objCmd.ExecuteScalar();


byte[] byteArray;
                BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
                bf.Serialize(ms, result);
                byteArray = ms.ToArray(); // Byte Array
                ms.Close();

                ms = new MemoryStream(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
                ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                System.Drawing.Image returnImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms);`enter code here`
```

Error Statement : "Parameter is not valid"

Comment: You will need a PDF renderer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the stream that you're trying to write to an image is the byte representation of an actual PDF, so that won't work.

You can use tools such as [ImageMagick](https://github.com/dlemstra/Magick.NET/tree/master/Documentation) - that is a .NET wrapper for the library which will allow you to convert a PDF to image. That will actually figure out what the PDF looks like when rendered and will turn it into an image.

> ImageMagick is a powerful image manipulation library that supports
>   over 100 major file formats (not including sub-formats). With
>   Magick.NET you can use ImageMagick without having to install
>   ImageMagick on your server or desktop. Visit
>   https://github.com/dlemstra/Magick.NET/tree/master/Documentation
>   before installing to help you decide the best version.

Comment: But I would want to convert a pdf byte array to image. I have been trying many codes but the error message seems to be the same

Comment: @Phoenix you can't convert raw bytes in that way to an image as the bytes actually represent the PDF content (text, positions, images etc) - you need something to render the PDF and turn that into an image.

Comment: Imagemagick uses Ghostscript to rasterize the PDF file into an image. So you could just use Ghostscript to do the processing without using Imagemagick.

Comment: Even iText uses ImageMagick&Ghostscript to render PDF files to images, in the iText tests (see for yourself on GitHub).

Comment: I tried using GhostScript : -                                               
    rasterizer.Open(inputFile) This returns page count 0